# Eager loading a tree in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, eager-loading

I have a problem trying to load a tree, this is my case, I have an entity associated with itself (Hierarchic) with n levels; the question is, Can I load eagerly the entire tree using ICriteria or HQL?

Thanks in advance for any help.
Ariel

Answer (score 1):

Yes... just set correct fetchmode.

---

i'll include example in a minute.

---

Example taken [from here](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) =>

```
IList cats = sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat))
    .Add( Expression.Like("Name", "Fritz%") )
    .SetFetchMode("Mate", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("Kittens", FetchMode.Eager)
    .List();
```

You can specify to eager load child of child too =>

```
.SetFetchMode("Kittens.BornOn", FetchMode.Eager)
```

---

In case you are using Linq to NHibernate, use Expand method =>

```
var feedItemQuery = from ad in session.Linq<FeedItem>().Expand("Ads")
                           where ad.Id == Id
                           select ad;
```

---

And i would recommend to use helper method that creates string from passed in lambda expression.

---

Quite likely that it's possible to tell Criteria to load whole tree. But i'm not aware about that and i prefer specifying what exactly i need (seems dangerous to load everything).

---

Does [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/28/nhibernate-tips-amp-tricks-efficiently-selecting-a-tree.aspx) helps?

Comment: I know I can load collections related to an entity using FetchMode, but I want to load the entire tree, not only the next level.
Using your approach I would do:


    .SetFetchMode("Children", FetchMode.Join)

    .SetFetchMode("Children.Children", FetchMode.Join)

    .SetFetchMode("Children.Children.Children", FetchMode.Join) etc